# How to pinpoint leak detected via valgrind but missing debuginfo?

Tags: c++, valgrind

On running valgrind through a program I compiled, I get the following snippet of an output:

```
==80341== HEAP SUMMARY:
==80341==     in use at exit: 6,840 bytes in 27 blocks
==80341==   total heap usage: 107,314 allocs, 107,287 frees, 103,658,505 bytes allocated
==80341== 
==80341== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 27
==80341==    at 0x4843223: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:714)
==80341==    by 0x48A5986: _sub_I_65535_0.0 (commandlineflags.h:132)
==80341==    by 0x4004EED: call_init (dl-init.c:90)
==80341==    by 0x4004EED: call_init (dl-init.c:27)
==80341==    by 0x4004FDB: _dl_init (dl-init.c:137)
==80341==    by 0x401B2CF: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
==80341==    by 0x8: ???
==80341==    by 0x1FFF0000C2: ???
==80341==    by 0x1FFF0000D8: ???
==80341==    by 0x1FFF0000DF: ???
==80341==    by 0x1FFF000126: ???
==80341==    by 0x1FFF00012E: ???
==80341==    by 0x1FFF000147: ???
==80341==

...

==80341== LEAK SUMMARY:
==80341==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==80341==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==80341==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==80341==    still reachable: 6,832 bytes in 26 blocks
==80341==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

This trace is confusing to me. I suspect this involves `ld-linux-x86-64.so` which may not have debug symbols and is why is having problems. I have other parts of code which valgrind can pinpoint traces to (which I hope is a separate problem).

Is this from my application or some valgrind artifact? Running a few normal programs give me a clean run, so I suspect this is part of my program.

How do I debug this situation to pinpoint which part of my program is causing this behaviour?

Comment: *through a program I compiled* - go recompile and relink with `-g` and get everything you need. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: Also, what's going on around line 132 of `commandlineflags.h` ?  That may or may not be your code.

Comment: @selbie:  This is from a debug build (`-g`) is added. Please find the larger memcheck.log at https://gist.github.com/jerinphilip/bb59d1c08904e9090bf052c8345caa7d (with parts indicating `-g` present). This is a part of the code that is claimed to be lost guaranteed, except I don't currently know how to get symbols and locations from the trace posted - hence this question.

Comment: Did you use anything, depending on the dll? If it is a default linked linux library, check what OS API your code is invoking.

Comment: My guess is this is coming from https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-init.c;h=ffd05b78069432d9140df1b0bbecfa3dad116e3d;hb=HEAD#l125. This is perhaps trying to access malloc going via tcmalloc (gperftools: https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/master/src/base/commandlineflags.h), then going to valgrind's malloc overload (vg_replace_malloc).

(excuse the terminology, I'm not an expert)

Answer (score 1):

It’s the line below `new` that matters:

`==80341==    by 0x48A5986: _sub_I_65535_0.0 (commandlineflags.h:132)`

It’s probably something like a file static that gets initialized when your exe or shared library is loaded. Look at the line indicated above, commandlinflags.h line 132.

Comment: I do not own `commandlineflags.h`, nor do I know where I can find this at the moment. The trace appears to go through `ld-linux---` to something `valgrind`, is it safe to assume this is not from my application code?  I have posted the full log in comments to the original question.

Comment: _I do not own commandlineflags.h, nor do I know where I can find this at the moment_ well you need to track down a copy

Comment: As mentioned in other comment, I suspect this is https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/master/src/base/commandlineflags.h (glibc load for malloc -> tcmalloc (gperftools) -> valgrind malloc overload). Assuming I can trace down the source with clues, is there any possibility to improve the trace?

Comment: You have many mismatched free errors. These are probably not serious and due to a compiler optimization - tail call optimization. This optimization means Valgrind doesn’t see the full call stack and so misses out the `delete[]` part. Try `--show-mismatched-frees=no` . Alternatively building your code with  `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`  might also work.

Comment: Is your tcmalloc built with Valgrind support? As a fallback it checks the RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND environment variable, try setting that to 1.